# Why I am getting Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_identifiers'

Tags: python, pandas, apply, attributeerror

I am using this code to extract column names from a column of sql queries; however, it is giving me error: 'Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_identifiers'

My code is :

```
import sqlparse

def get_query_columns(sql):
    stmt = sqlparse.parse(sql)[0]
    columns = []
    column_identifiers = []

    # get column_identifieres
    in_select = False
    for token in stmt.tokens:
        if isinstance(token, sqlparse.sql.Comment):
            continue
        if str(token).lower() == 'select':
            in_select = True
        elif in_select and token.ttype is None:
            for identifier in token.get_identifiers():
                column_identifiers.append(identifier)
            break

    # get column names
    for column_identifier in column_identifiers:
        columns.append(column_identifier.get_name())

    return columns


dfff['SQL_TEXT'].apply(get_query_columns)
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
Input In [1069], in get_query_columns(sql)
     14     in_select = True
     15 elif in_select and token.ttype is None:
---> 16     for identifier in token.get_identifiers():
     17         column_identifiers.append(identifier)
     18     break

AttributeError: 'Identifier' object has no attribute 'get_identifiers'
```

How can I structure it so if I use apply method on get_query_columns function, it does not give me error.

Thanks

Comment: The `token` you have IS an `Identifier`.  You can't fetch an identifier from an identifier.  I don't know what you are trying to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for comment, how can I rectify it?

Comment: As I said, I can't tell what you're trying to do here.  You need to print out the token itself -- maybe you already have a column.